# PHP save array value if match to Session

Tags: php

I have an Input submit form and i want if an user enters an number thats match with my `array value`, the Card Brand saves to PHP Session on next site.

```
<?php    
    $submitbutton= $_POST['btnLogin'];    
    $number= $_POST['Kreditkartennummer'];

    function validatecard($number)
    {
        global $type;

        $cardtype = array(
            "visa"       => "/^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/",
            "mastercard" => "/^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/",
            "amex"       => "/^3[47][0-9]{13}$/",
            "discover"   => "/^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/",
        );

        if (preg_match($cardtype['visa'],$number))
        {
            $type= "visa";
            return 'visa';          
        }
        else if (preg_match($cardtype['mastercard'],$number))
        {
            $type= "mastercard";
            return 'mastercard';
        }
        else if (preg_match($cardtype['amex'],$number))
        {
            $type= "amex";
            return 'amex';          
        }
        else if (preg_match($cardtype['discover'],$number))
        {
            $type= "discover";
            return 'discover';
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        } 
    }    
    validatecard($number);    
?>
```

The Question now, works it with my Code? or needs an `"If Submit"`?
The other question how can i echo the `return` and save it to my php `Session`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save something to your session variable all you have to do is declare it so.

```
$_SESSION['card_type'] = $_POST['card_type'];
```

for example let's say this is your form. This is only an example.

```
<form type="POST">
<input type="text" name="card_type">
<input type="submit" value="submit my form">
</form>
```

in this form, you have an input with the name card_type, when this is submitted you can get the value from that input like so.

```
    if(isset($_POST['card_type'])) {
    $_SESSION['card_type'] = $_POST['card_type']; //you are taking the post and making a session variable.
}
```

I know this only explains the last part of your questions, I just did not understand the first part.

edit..I also wanted to point out that you do not just want to accept the user input without some type of validation. Put you validation code after you check if there has been a post.